# rooting my android phone by an app like kingroot

Tags: android, mobile, root, huawei-developers

I want to root my phone(android:9,model: Huawei P30 lite) I used kingroot but after 16% it says 'root faild no strategy now'. Do you know what should I do?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: Most likely this means your device can not be rooted by KingRoot. Huawei devices are usually un-rootable and Huawei has stopped to official way to unlock&root devices years ago.